# Battery discharging while plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a new 2019 MacBook Pro 16" on Catalina 10.15.5. I recently got it back from the shop - upper case replacement for bad keyboard that included replacing the battery as part of the repair. Now occasionally when plugged in the battery charge actually decreases. For instance last night I opened it, it was plugged in at 100%. I used it to make an email and print a few pages for 15 minutes and the charge actually decreased to 93%. The icon shows when plugged in.

What would cause this? Ideas?

Does anyone else have a MBP that decreases the battery charge while plugged?

Comment: This is a dupe of the exact same question you recently asked.  The original was closed because it’s a duplicate of another.  If you feel it’s different, then you need to edit it to show how and why it’s different.  Re-asking the exact same question will get it closed

Comment: ummm, i did edit it.  this is the edited version.

Comment: @Stumped Edit it in place.. then we can reopen it.

Comment: You only edited small text.

Comment: Please know that we can see your edit history and you need to [edit the original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/395867/edit) not post a new question.   Once you edit a question that has been closed for any reason, it will automatically be put into a queue to vote on for re-opening.